# Как разобрать по составу слова "недоумевать", "недоумок"?

Tags: морфемный-разбор

Надо действовать по инструкции, которая называется **"план морфемного разбора":**

"Выписать слово в той форме, в какой оно представлено в предложении. Определить слово как часть речи (изменяемая или неизменяемая часть речи).
У изменяемого слова выделить окончание и указать его значение. 
Указать основу слова. Выделить корень слова; подобрать однокоренные слова.
Выделить приставки, суффиксы, постфиксы, соединительные гласные (если они есть); подобрать другие слова с такими же приставками, суффиксами и т.д., но с другим корнем".

**Решение.** Недоумевать  — это значит не постигать умом. Можно предположить, что здесь корень **"ум"**. А какая приставка: ***не-*** или ***недо-***? Наверное, ***недо-*** со значением неполноты действия.
А вот и однокоренные слова: **недо**умение, **недо**уменный, **недо**умие, **недо**умок  — вроде бы все эти слова имеют одинаковый корень "ум".

Получаем: ***недо/ум/ева/ть, недо/ум/ок.*** Смотрим ответ в словаре Тихонова: нет, неверно.
**А почему?**

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54576/discussion-on-question-by-sergey-------).

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю, что  не/до/у́м/ок/ - это человек "неумный", "глуповатый", "тот, которому ума не хватает". И здесь очевидна лексическая связь со словом "ум".
Слово "недоумевать" отчасти потеряло своё значение и связь со словом "ум" явно не прослеживается,  оно уже не обозначает "поглупеть", а скорее обозначает "сомневаться", "быть озадаченным", "раздумывать", "не решаться". Поэтому произошло переразложение, приставка слилась с корнем, и образец разбора стал выглядеть следующим образом: недоум/ева́/ть

Comment: А когда слово "недоумевать" обозначало "поглупеть"? В первый раз о таком слышу, в толковых и этимологических словарях подтверждения не нашёл. "Недоумевать" значит, по сути, "недопонимать", а отсюда до "сомневаться" и "быть озадаченным" рукой подать. Переразложение необоснованно.

Comment: Уважаемый Пересвет! Убираем из данного предложения наречие УЖЕ, и  всё встанет на свои места. Слово "недоумевать" отчасти потеряло своё значение и связь со словом "ум" явно не прослеживается, оно НЕ обозначает (если хотите и НЕ обозначало, хотя НЕ ФАКТ!) "поглупеть", а скорее, обозначает "сомневаться", "быть озадаченным", "раздумывать", "не решаться".

Comment: Почему Вы решили, что это слово *отчасти потеряло своё значение*? Откройте словарь Даля и увидите, что оно ещё тогда обозначало *сомневаться, быть озадаченным, в раздумье, не решаться, колебаться*, что прямо следует из древнего значения глагола **уметь** (вот он как раз поменял свой смысл с тех пор). Почему Вы решили, что связь со словом **ум** не прослеживается? По-моему, она очевидна любому носителю языка. И при чём тут вообще **поглупеть**? **Недоумевать** не имело и не имеет такого значения.

Answer (score 0):

Здесь возможны три варианта разбора — 1) *недо-ум-ева-ть* (Потиха), 2) *недоуме-ва-ть* (Тихонов, "Комплексный словарь русского языка"), 3) недо-ум-е-ва-ть (Кузнецова, Ефремова). На мой взгляд, логичнее вариант 3, но это, как говорится, дело вкуса — корректны все и в одинаковой степени.

Во-первых, стоит заметить, что приставка *не-* выделяться здесь не может никак — слова "доумевать" нет. Во-вторых, в случае 2 наблюдается деэтимологизация, т. е. утрата связи слова с историческим корнем — ум, в связи с чем и не выделяется приставка *недо-*. В-третьих, вопрос количества суффиксов для школы совершенно не важен, поэтому стоит выбрать любой из предложенных вариантов.

Разбор слова "недоумок" — по аналогии: 1) *недо-ум-ок-ø*, 2) *недоум-ок-ø*.

Не уверен, что здесь, на сайте, стоит выполнять полностью разбор по предложенному вами плану — все трудности, могущие возникнуть, вроде бы объяснены.